# Express.js cannot connect to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Im on OS x. Im running an express.js app. This is what I have in app.js:

```
var express    = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cn = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
mongoose.connect(cn, function(error) {
    console.log("inside?");
    console.log(res);
});
console.log("outside");
```

If I open a terminal a write:

```
mongo
```

then I see this:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.3
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-04-13T16:25:17.440+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-04-13T16:25:17.440+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-04-13T16:25:17.440+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-04-13T16:25:17.440+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> show dbs
admin  0.000GB
local  0.000GB
test   0.000GB
```

When I run

```
node app.js
```

The only thing I see in the terminal is:

```
outside
```

So it never goes inside "connect"? I have a callback because I realized that when I tried to communicate with database the code hangs up. I dont get any error message but it seems I never can query mongodb from express. What is wrong? I have tried several different connection string, for example 127.0.0.1 or even 127.0.0.1:27017 but no luck.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand JavaScript's asynchronous nature. "outside" will always be printed before the database connection callback.

Comment: ??? I am aware of that. Im just saying that "inside" is never printed.

Comment: It NEVER goes inside that function. It doesn't help if I print the error as it won't show up. The connection fails bacause it never executed code inside the callback. However, I don't see any error printed anywhere.

Comment: Never mind my last comment... So what version of Mongoose is installed?

Comment: MongoDB server version: 3.4.3. Installed it with brew, Im on osx. Strange thing is that it worked before. Yesterday worked. Im not sure what happened. If it is some change in the code or something else.

Comment: Actually, I mean the version of the `mongoose` package. Is it up to date?

Comment: version is 3.6.13

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong your code, you will get reponse after outside because node.js is not blocking the next code execution, once callback return the value you will get the output. its working for me.

```
 var express    = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var cn = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
    mongoose.connect(cn, function(error) {
        console.log("inside?");
        console.log(error);
    });
    console.log("outside");
```

**output console**:

```
outside
inside?
undefined
```

Comment: Unfortunately the callback is never executed. However, it seems its a mongo issue. Seems like service is not started (but i dont understand why i can connect from terminal client)

Comment: please upgrade mongoose version like mongoose@4.9.4

Comment: I said the problem is not mongoose, but mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'async' or putting the connection initialization part inside a promise will make sure that the execution gets blocked till the connection has been made.

```
await mongoose.connect(cn, function(error) {
  console.log("inside?");
  console.log(res);
});
```

If you're using await make sure the function has the async keyword.

Using a promise:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
mongoose.connection.on('open', () => {
  debug('Connection successfully made');
  resolve();
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', () => {
  debug('Error occurred');
  reject();
});
```

});